# Order divs alphabetically and place empty divs at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I alphabetically order divs by the content of `.instructor`:

```
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = jQuery('.entry').sort(function(a, b) {
    var $aTitle = jQuery(a).find('.instructor'), $bTitle = jQuery(b).find('.instructor');
    return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($aTitle.text().toLowerCase(), $bTitle.text().toLowerCase());
});
```

It works great.

However, if `.instructor` is empty, it places the empty div at the top. My question is, how can I add the empty ones **at the bottom of the list**?

So currently, it returns:

```
empty
a
b
c
...
```

### Edit

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkx2tdu0/). Notice how the empty div is added the top of the alphabetically ordered divs. I want it at the bottom.

Comment: May you include a code snippet (use `<>` in the question editor)?

Comment: `if (jQuery('.entry') !== null) {code}`?

Comment: after sorting, while empty title, detach and attach at the end

Comment: @evolutionxbox Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkx2tdu0/). Notice how the empty div is added to the very top.

Comment: Please put the runnable code into question into the question itself. JSFiddle links rot and become useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.prototype.localeCompare` places reference string (`$aTitle`) after comparable string if method returns positive value. So you need return any positive value to place down empty titles:

```
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.entry').sort(function (a, b) {
    var $aTitle = $(a).find('.title'), $bTitle = $(b).find('.title');

    if (!$aTitle.text()) return 1;
    if (!$bTitle.text()) return -1;

    return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($aTitle.text().toLowerCase(), $bTitle.text().toLowerCase());
});
```

This code works as follow:

1. If A is empty, place it after B
2. if A is not empty, but B is empty, place B after A (return -1)
3. if none of strings are empty, sort them by value

Here is your updated snippet:

```js
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.entry').sort(function (a, b) {
    var $aTitle = $(a).find('.title'), $bTitle = $(b).find('.title');
    
    if (!$aTitle.text()) return 1;
    if (!$bTitle.text()) return -1;
    
    return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($aTitle.text().toLowerCase(), $bTitle.text().toLowerCase());
    });

var container = $(".container");
container.detach().empty().append(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
$('body').append(container);
```

```css
.entry {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="entry">
    <div class="title">World</div>
  </div>

  <div class="entry">
    <div class="title">hello</div>
  </div>

  <div class="entry">
    <div class="title"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="entry">
    <div class="title">Lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could potentially do something like this?

```
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $('.entry').sort(function (a, b) {
    var $aTitle = $(a).find('.title'), $bTitle = $(b).find('.title');
    if ($bTitle.text().length === 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    if ($aTitle.text().length === 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($aTitle.text().toLowerCase(), $bTitle.text().toLowerCase());
});
```